# Making libinput touchpad configuration permanent

Tags: drivers, configuration, touchpad, libinput

I'm using libinput as touchpad driver for my laptop. I can configure the various settings using `xinput`, but can't find out a way to make these settings permanent. Looks like I need to edit the configuration file 
in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` by adding necessary options. If that's the case, where can I find a list of various options supported by libinput?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out the manual page for `libinput`? You haven't mentioned your distribution, but the Debian version of the documentation can be found [here](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/xserver-xorg-input-libinput/libinput.4.en.html).

Answer (score 0):

`Option "NaturalScrolling" "on"`

solved it for me.

had to add this option to the configuration file. It was the `30-touchpad.conf` file in
`/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

small list of other options:
https://wiki.debian.org/LibinputTouchpad